# What does $\ln$ mean by itself?

Tags: calculus, notation

I have a few questions in my homework that as me to integrate $1 \over {3 + \ln - 2x}$ 
I thought $\ln$ was a function, why is it by itself? What does it mean?

Comment: Some texts don't use parenthesis.  Maybe it means $\ln(-2x)$.

Comment: I think you need to ask whoever set the problem to clarify it.

Comment: @randomgirl That makes..... sense... thanks lol

Comment: I don't  understand  why some texts do that.  It can make it hard to understand. For example, how do we know it doesn't mean $\ln(-2)x$?

Comment: I think the suggestion is that it’s like $\sin 2\theta$. Nobody uses parentheses for that. And I seriously doubt anybody thinks it means $(\sin 2)\cdot\theta$.

Comment: @MPW I use parenthese for that. In fact, why not, it makes it clearer and removes all possible confusion. If at all, I'd only use it as a sort of shorthand for personal stuff. And never have I seen it done with a negative sign.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt. I totally agree with you on that. (about parentheses)

Comment: Writting sin(x) is a recent fad.. @SimplyBeautifulArt

Comment: Personally, I would always *write* $\sin (x), \log(x), \sin(2x), \log(9y)$, but I would type $\sin y, \log z; \sin(3x), \log(2y)$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt : I would use them with the minus sign too. Look, I’m only pointing out what I thought was meant in another comment. But it’s pretty standard to omit the parentheses when the argument is just $x$ or $nx$, and to use them with $-kx$ or $k+x$.

Comment: @MPW In response to the comment "*Nobody* uses parentheses for that" (emphasis added), I would reply that you are incorrect.  Many people use parentheses for that (including me).  Moreover, while I would not begrudge the notation $\ln 2x$ in a more advanced context, I would absolutely insist on writing $\ln(2x)$ in front of elementary students, who barely understand what a function is, and are easily thrown off by poor, inconsistent notation.  The fact that it is "pretty standard" does not mean that it is **good**.

Comment: @XanderHenderson : I stand by my statement. I'm sure many people use parentheses, but it is uncommon for textbooks to routinely use them. *Students* often tend to use them because they are sometimes confused by the function notation without parentheses. But most textbooks *do not* routinely use them. As a test, I just googled **textbook logarithm** and none of the first half-dozen links I checked used them. (By "routinely", I mean using "$\ln(7)$" instead of "$\ln 7$".) Of course, they should always be used if there is any doubt or if the expression needs to be clarified.

Comment: @XanderHenderson : ... (cont'd) I've seen students use $\sqrt{(x+y)}$ instead fo $\sqrt{x+y}$ too, but they are equally unnecessary there as well.

Comment: @MPW I don't think that anyone is arguing with your assertion that omission of the parentheses is common.  I believe that the pushback you are getting is to the overly inclusive language, i.e. "**Nobody** uses parentheses for that."  I agree that many elementary textbooks omit parentheses---I am not arguing otherwise.  I am simply pointing out that (1) not everybody omits the parentheses (contra your original comment) and (2) the fact that it is common does not make it good.

Comment: And I think that $\sqrt{(x+y)}$ is a different case (unless they are writing $\sqrt{}(x+y)$.).  In the case of trigonometric functions and logarithms, I think that it is good pedagogical practice to include the parentheses (while noting that many authors will omit them) in order to emphasize that these are *functions*.  After all, we want to avoid things like $$\frac{\sin x}{x} = \sin $$ by cancelation of the $x$'s.

Comment: @XanderHenderson : Okay, understood. I concede that my “Nobody” is an exaggeration

Comment: @MPW Then we are in agreement!  Huzzah! Can I get you a beer?

Comment: @XanderHenderson : )

Answer (score 1):

By $~\ln x~$ or, $~\ln(x)~$ we mean **logarithm of $~x~$ to the base $~e~$**.

You can also say it as [**Natural Logarithm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm).

> **Definition:** When $~e^y = x~$, then with respect to base $~e~$ logarithm of $~x~$ is 
>   $$\ln(x) = \log_e(x) = y$$The $~e~$, constant or Euler's number is: $~e ≈ 2.71828183~$.

---

Your $~\dfrac{1}{3 + \ln - 2x}~$ is nothing but $~\dfrac{1}{3 + \ln(- 2x)}~$